# How can I adjust the code for my Next.js form to correct a prisma error?

Tags: forms, next.js, server, client

I am creating an ecommerce website using the MERN stack.

Currently, I am creating a form using next.js to enter data into my database. However, I'm getting the following errors.

It says "Error: missing required fields" after I entered the data into every field. Also I've made sure to enter the correct data type in each.

I believe something was wrong with my If statement for blank entries:
[Error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pan0f.png)

Actual "if Statement":

```
if (!name || !description || !imageUrl || !price) {
    throw Error("Missing required fields");
}
```

I reviewed the code and I could not figure out what was wrong with the "Image URL" input tag or its attributes, or the problem on the prisma end.

So  I removed the following condition:

```
if (!name || !description || !imageUrl || !price) {
    throw Error("Missing required fields");
}
```

Then a I got the following error:

[Error Message after removing the "If Statement"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k7vO.png)

What error in my code am I missing? Thanks for your help.